# What exactly happens when i use awk and redirect this output to another awk command?

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

does the output of the first awk command come line by line to the next awk command?
For example, given file 1:

```
123,1
111,2
345,3
555,4
```

Then:

```
awk -F"," '{print $0}' | awk -F"," '{print $2}'
```

I want to know how the awk command works internally.

Comment: On a side note, it is normally a bad idea to pipe different `awk` commands, because in most of the cases what you want to do can be done in just one call of `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

No. The whole output of the first awk will be piped to 2nd, that is, `awk... file|awk...` will start two awk processes, not `1+ file.NumOfLine()` processes.

```
kent$  cat f
one
two
three

kent$  awk '7' f|awk '{print NR,$0}'
1 one
2 two
3 three
```

you see `1,2,3` in final output, not `1,1,1`

And this has nothing to do with "how the awk command works internally.", you may want to read something about `pipe`